# Copied \AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup to another computer but files not showing

Tags: backup, notepad++

I copied files in \AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup to another computer (new win10 SSD) but **only new 1 is showing when I launch Notepad++**.  This used to work fine - has anything changed with the last few releases?

[Pic of the 2 files listed in \backup\](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRlP6.png)

I don't see any difference between the 2 files yet new 1 was created on the new computer and new 13 was copied.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be other files are hidden?

Comment: I have a folder c:\temp which is permitted to “Everyone”.  I usually copy files here and make sure the copy was successful. Then copy to the other computer.  This avoids any permission errors.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else had the same question recently.  Answer:
https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21634/not-remembering-backup-files-when-opening/3?_=1629485002073&lang=en-US

"...it isn’t the presence of files in that folder that cause Notepad++ to open them; it is the presence of the entries for those files in session.xml".  I changed my username slightly with the new system and so, although I had copied session.xml, it was silently failing due to the different username in the file paths.